# What is the most effective gstreamer pipeline for streaming a GoPro Hero 8 over Wifi?

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, gopro

I am trying to stream a gopro hero 8 over wifi using konradIT's goprowifihack: https://github.com/KonradIT/goprowifihack. I can do this fairly well by using Mission Planner, right-clicking the HUD, Video->set Gstreamer source, and entering

`udpsrc port=8554 ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert !  video/x-raw,format=BGRA ! appsink name=outsink`.

In Mission Planner, the video comes through relatively clearly, but I would like to be able to stream without using Mission Planner. I've tried to develop my own pipeline based off of the one I use for MP. The current pipeline I am using is:

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=8554 loop=true ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert !  video/x-raw,format=BGRA ! autovideosink sync=False`

However, the video still appears very choppy and glitchy. I have experimented by adding and changing different parameters for udpsrc, including mtu, blocksize, and buffer-size. These make no difference for me. What is the best gstreamer pipeline to use for clear and consistent video?